# How to extract the particular string in XML without Parsing in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have received the data using NSURLConnection and i got the following strings, which is XML formats of string. Now i want to take the status node of string. I want to take that string without using XML parsing.

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

     NSString *urlDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.recieveData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Return String:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Utf-8"?><blacksheep><status>Success</status></blacksheep>
```

Output:

```
  Succeess
```

PLease help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: You *have* to parse the XML so you can extract the string inside the `<status>` and `</status>` tags.  You maybe wanted to say you don't want to do it *manually*.

Comment: @Eduardo León, Thanks for your comment. Actually i have received the xml strings, so how can i parsed the strings using NSXML parser? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString* str = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"Utf-8\"?><blacksheep><status>Success</status></blacksheep>";
NSString* status = [[[[str componentsSeparatedByString: @"<status>"] objectAtIndex: 1] componentsSeparatedByString: @"</status>"] objectAtIndex: 0];
```

But be careful: this is short but not very safe method. So you'd better add some additional checks.

Edit: better way is

```
NSString* status = @"Failed";
NSArray* arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"<status>"];
if( [arr count] > 1 ) {
      status = [[[arr objectAtIndex: 1] componentsSeparatedByString: @"</status>"] objectAtIndex: 0];
}
```

Comment: +1, @Max, Thanks for reply, you have mentioned as "this is short but not very safe method". If i have used parsing, it will take some times for processing for XML parsing. so that i planned to avoid the XML parsing. And one more, in my case there is only one string will return like status. And status string is always return success or failure. So can i use that method in my apps? please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think full XML parsing would be too much for your purposes.

Comment: If XML parsing is too much for his purposes, then XML itself is too much for his purposes, don't'cha think? Why not send a single char (`S` or `F`) instead of a full-blown XML string? It wastes less bandwith, whose lack thereof is more likely to be the real bottleneck of his application.

Comment: I don't know the purposes. I just say that it's shorter and easier to implement without parser in this case.